# asp.net using different App_Code folder

Tags: asp.net, app-code

1. I created folder "Test" under my web site root.
2. Under this folder I created another App_Code folder and put my class code there.
3. I also add default.aspx under Test folder.

In my code behind I cannot access class code. Only classes under top App_Code is available.

How can I access code under second App_Code? I tried to add same namespace for page and class, but this does not help.

Comment: Is this a web site project or a web application project? And are you trying to embed one site inside another?

Comment: Are these files (your class code) included in the project or are they just in the directory structure?

Comment: I have web site project. Class code include in project

Answer (score 2):

You must put all class code inside the `App_Code` folder from the root folder. One trick would be to create a `Test` folder inside the main `App_Code` folder. You are allowed to put as many subfolders as you need.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23(v=vs.140).aspx